# Inner Join twice in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

im having an issue with my inner join,these are my tables with FK and PK

```
TABLE CITY
city_id (PK)
city_name
state

TABLE DEPOT
dep_id (PK)
capacity
city_id (FK) references CiTy

TABLE MANUFACTURER
manu_id (PK)
manu_name
city_id (FK) references city
```

so i just want to make the result look like this:

```
DEPOT_CITY_name(referencese from city_id), MANUFACTURER_CITY_name(references from city_id)
```

thanks

Comment: But how do the tables relate to each other?

Comment: @jarith is right. Right now the only thing you have to relate these two things to each other is the city name, in which case your answer is going to be the same city for each depot/manufactured combination, so your desired query results don't even make sense to do. We need more detail about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

List the table twice in the from clause with different aliases.

This will give you different cities, one for the manufacturer and one for the depot.

```
SELECT dc.city_name AS depot_city
,      mc.city_name AS manufacturer_city
FROM   DEPOT AS d
JOIN   CITY AS dc
    ON dc.city_id = d.city_id
JOIN   MANUFACTURER AS m
    ON m.some_column = d.some_column -- or however these tables relate
JOIN   CITY AS mc
    ON mc.city_id = m.city_id
```

Comment: I agree with what you are saying here, but can't upvote a use of a SQL antipattern (Select *).

Comment: @HLGEM - SELECT was fixed to only return the fields the OP asked for

Answer (score 0):

Just do two left joins on cityid :

```
select depot.city_id, Manufacturer.city_id from

depot  left join city on city.city_id = depot.city_id
       left join Manufacturer on Manufacturer.city_id = city.city_id
```